# Why is this SQL error happening?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to install KBAffiliate php script but am having great troubles trying to import the SQL, Any advice?

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `scraffiliateusr` (
  `usrid` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `usract` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrnam` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,
  `usrpwd` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,
  `usractkey` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,
  `usrip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,
  `usreml` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,
  `usrjondtetme` datetime NOT NULL default `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
  `usrinvby` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrlstvstdtetme` datetime NOT NULL default `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
  `usrvst` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrvsttdy` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrprflstvstdtetme` datetime NOT NULL default `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
  `usrprfvst` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrprfvsttdy` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrinvlstsnddtetme` datetime NOT NULL default `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
  `usrinvsnd` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrinvsndtdy` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrinvurllstclkdtetme` datetime NOT NU[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`0`,   `usrnam` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ``,   `usrpwd`
>   varchar(100) NOT ' at line 3

Comment: I don't think that two backticks is allowed.  You should use single quotes for the default for the string columns.

Comment: Did not work,SQL query:


-- 
-- Table structure for table `scraffiliateusr`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `scraffiliateusr` (
  `usrid` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `usract` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
  `usrnam` varchar(100) NOT NULL default `,
  `usrpwd` varchar(100) NOT NULL default `,
  `usractkey` varchar(100) NOT NULL default `,
  `usrip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default `,
  `usreml` varchar(100) NOT NULL default `,

Comment: I would assume you meant the bits ` `  like that?

Comment: Don't use the "bits" use single quotes, but not for numeric type values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `telda` with `'` your query work properly like example

```
    CREATE TABLE `scraffiliateusr1` (
  `usrid` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `usract` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrnam` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usrpwd` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usractkey` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usrip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usreml` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usrjondtetme` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usrinvby` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrlstvstdtetme` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usrvst` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrvsttdy` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrprflstvstdtetme` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usrprfvst` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrprfvsttdy` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrinvlstsnddtetme` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usrinvsnd` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrinvsndtdy` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrinvurllstclkdtetme` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usrinvurlclk` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrinvurlclktdy` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrinvsndmax` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrpoints` float NOT NULL default 0,
  `usrpointsindirect` float NOT NULL default 0,
  `usr24` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usr25` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usr26` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `usr27` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`usrid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 

INSERT INTO `scraffiliateusr` (`usrid`, `usract`, `usrnam`, `usrpwd`, `usractkey`, `usrip`, `usreml`, `usrjondtetme`, `usrinvby`, `usrlstvstdtetme`, `usrvst`, `usrvsttdy`, `usrprflstvstdtetme`, `usrprfvst`, `usrprfvsttdy`, `usrinvlstsnddtetme`, `usrinvsnd`, `usrinvsndtdy`, `usrinvurllstclkdtetme`, `usrinvurlclk`, `usrinvurlclktdy`, `usrinvsndmax`, `usrpoints`, `usrpointsindirect`, `usr24`, `usr25`, `usr26`, `usr27`) VALUES 
(1001, 1, 'user', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, '2008-02-24 19:05:46', 10, 11, '2008-02-24 07:40:54', 2, 1, '2008-02-24 19:06:09', 2, 1, '2008-02-24 17:40:27', 2, 1, 5, 20, 9,'','','', ''),
(1002, 1, 'user2', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1001, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2008-02-24 19:05:58', 4, 8, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 2, 11, 0,'','','', ''),
(1003, 1, 'user3', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1001, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2008-02-24 07:22:42', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1004, 1, 'user4', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1001, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2008-02-24 07:28:29', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1005, 1, 'user5', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1002, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2008-02-24 07:29:26', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 4, 10, 0,'','','', ''),
(1006, 1, 'user6', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1003, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1007, 1, 'user7', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1004, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1008, 1, 'user8', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1004, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1009, 1, 'user9', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1004, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1010, 1, 'user10', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1004, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1011, 1, 'user11', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1005, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2008-02-20 12:38:26', 0, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 4, 10, 0,'','','', ''),
(1012, 1, 'user12', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1005, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1013, 1, 'user13', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1008, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 4, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1014, 1, 'user14', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1009, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,'','','', ''),
(1015, 1, 'user15', 'password','','','', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1014, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,'','','', '');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scraffiliateurlclk` (
  `urlclkid` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `urlclkusrid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `urlclkipaddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `urlclktmestmp` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 0,
  `urlclk4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`urlclkid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Still not any luck

Comment: This is the full SQL String
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86ba1a4cb778955707f1e1d30d5c5964

Comment: The revision did not work, Could there be anything set up wrong on phpmyadmin?

Comment: I did have SQL data before i deleted my old site and started installing new

Comment: Replace the backticks around the field names as well - scratch that - see my answer

Comment: please replace file with these one content

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `scraffiliateusr` (`usrid`, `usract`, `usrnam`, `usrpwd`, `usractkey' at line 34

Comment: Why is it not working, This is really winding me up :( Thank you for the help BTW!

Answer (score 2):

```
`usract` int(11) NOT NULL default `0`,
```

This is wrong in multiple layers of wrongness.  First, you are putting the default value zero into quotes, when it should be left unescaped because it is a raw integer.  But the quotes you are using are actually backticks, but they should be single quotes.  So this line should look like this:

```
`usract' int(11) NOT NULL default 0
```

The timestamp fields should use single quotes:

```
'usrjondtetme' datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Comment: I have made the adjustments but still cant get it loaded, I AM RUBBISH AT SQL Hence why im asking for help.

Comment: Was it you TIM that made a revision? As it still errors. COULD it be an issue with my cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

In fact I don't think you need to have quotes around the table and field names.....

```
CREATE TABLE scraffiliateusr (
  usrid bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  usract int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrnam varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usrpwd varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usractkey varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usrip varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usreml varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usrjondtetme datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  usrinvby int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrlstvstdtetme datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  usrvst int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrvsttdy int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrprflstvstdtetme datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  usrprfvst int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrprfvsttdy int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrinvlstsnddtetme datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  usrinvsnd int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrinvsndtdy int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrinvurllstclkdtetme datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  usrinvurlclk int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrinvurlclktdy int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrinvsndmax int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  usrpoints float NOT NULL default 0,
  usrpointsindirect float NOT NULL default 0,
  usr24 varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usr25 varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usr26 varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  usr27 varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (usrid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Hey ! 

AntDC This worked for just that table,

would you possibly be able to work your MAGIC on the import code?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86ba1a4cb778955707f1e1d30d5c5964

Comment: Not today - I'm up to my kneck.
Seeing as I answered your question, feel free to mark as the answer.  ;)